# Truncate all tables - Room

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-room

What is the fastest way to truncate all tables in Room Library? My goal is to clear the whole database using one RxJava **CompletableFromAction**. Is it possible to create **@Query** that deletes from many tables?

Comment: You might be able to use `;` to have multiple SQL statements in a `@Query` -- I have not tried that. Otherwise, you can use a `@Transaction` in the 1.0.0 beta to wrap individual-table truncation requests into a single transaction for speed.

Answer (score 0):

haven't test this but this might work

```
@Query("select 'drop table ' || name || ';' from sqlite_master where type = 'table';")
ReturnedType deleteEverything();
```

Comment: That drops tables; it does not truncate them.

Comment: yup, I also noticed it, btw I manage to find two ways to solve my problem, first is using rx **merge** operator and secound is using Room **@Transaction** annotation, non of it is one db query like I wanted, but I guess its the best I can do, thanks for Your help

Comment: @InvictaAnima can you provide your solution please?